# Bootstrap datepicker setting startdate fails

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using the Bootstrap Datapicker script (Link [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) and having problems setting the startdate.

> **Option: startDate**
>
> Date or String. Default: Beginning of time
>
> The earliest date that may be selected; all earlier dates will be disabled.
>
> Date should be in local timezone. String must be parsable with `format`.

**JavaScript:**

```
function initializeDatePicker() {
    if ($.isFunction($.fn.datepicker)) {
        var datepickerLang = lang;
        if (datepickerLang === "nl") {
            datepickerLang = "nl-BE";
        }

        $(".input-group.date input").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            todayBtn: "linked",
            clearBtn: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            language: datepickerLang,
            format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
            startDate: $(this).data("startdate")
        });
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-group date small">
    <input id="StartDate" class="form-control" name="StartDate" value="" data-is-required="True" data-startdate="01-12-2016" type="text">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What does work?**

If I hardcode the `startdate` to:

```
startDate: new Date() => today

startDate: "01-12-2016"
```

**What does not work?**

If I try to get the date from my data attribute nothing works.

```
startDate: new Date($(this).data("startdate")) => returns 'Date Invalid'

startDate: $(this).data("startdate")
```

I don't understand what is wrong and how I can fix it.

Comment: @GeorgeLee Does not work. If I hardcode the date it does work with "01/12/2016"

Comment: So if you log the value of "this" it turns out to be the document so you'll have to replace it with `$("#StartDate").data("startdate")`

Comment: Note that the datepicker supports data attributes init too, so in your case you can use `data-date-start-date` instead of `data-startdate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're using

```
$(this).data("startdate")
```

in this instance "this" is set to the document so it'll return null/undefined.
What you need to do is change it to this

```
$("#StartDate").data("startdate")
```

**----------------Edit---------------**

If you want to use this once on a page but have multiple datepickers you can use the data attributes insead, so remove the startDate from the options

```
$(".input-group.date input").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    clearBtn: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    language: datepickerLang,
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
});
```

And in your html add this attribute on the datapickers

```
data-date-start-date="01-12-2016"
```

Comment: The problem I have is that I have a function which sets the datapickers. This answer wont work for multiple datepickers. I added the full function in the question.

Comment: Ahh right in that case it may be better to go with the data attributes, I'll change my answer to reflect

Answer (score 4):

The datepicker supports [data attributes initialization](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#options), so you can use `data-date-start-date` in your HTML instead of `data-startdate`.

Here a working example:

```js
$(".input-group.date").datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  todayBtn: "linked",
  clearBtn: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
  language: 'nl',
  format: "dd-mm-yyyy"
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.nl.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date small" data-date-start-date="01-12-2016">
    <input id="StartDate" class="form-control" name="StartDate" value="" data-is-required="True" type="text">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that since you are using *component* markup, `data-date-*` attributes must be on the `div` instead of on th `input`, moreover your selector should be `$(".input-group.date")` instead of `$(".input-group.date input")`.

Comment: Completely forgot about this. This worked but I just had to change data-startdate to data-date-start-date mentioned in a answer below.

Comment: Small side question, maybe you know this. Want if I just want to show the calendar upon clicking the icon? Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: @NanouPonette adding `data-date-start-date` to `input` does not work for me, but it's ok to pick the other answer if it's fine for you. While I discourage asking new question in the comments, adding [`showOnFocus: false`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#showonfocus) will show calendar only when clicking the icon.

Comment: Thank you! You were very helpfull.

Comment: @VincenzoC It doesn't work on the input for you becuase your Jquery selector is not including the input fyi

Comment: @George thank you for the clarification. I've changed my selector to `$(".input-group.date")` according [demo](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) for type _component_.  Note that with my code you can open the picker clicking on calendar icon (as the OP asked later in the comments), while your code does not manage `input-group-addon`. Anyway I'm one of your answer's upvoters :D

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because $(this) in the startDate option is not a reference to the input element. You should use .each and set the datapicker for all of the elements in the selector one by one:

```
$(".input-group.date input").each(function () {
    $(this).datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: "linked",
        clearBtn: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        language: datepickerLang,
        format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
        startDate: $(this).data("startdate")
    })
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, be sûr to have the good value of your date data variable, for example by **printing it just before** constructing the datePicker.

Then, when you are sûr to have the good value with the good format, you can pass it to the startDate attribute :

- By giving the date string that must be parsable with "format"
- OR by constructing the Date object as flow : **new Date(yyyy,mm,dd)** 
  (by splitting the content of your data variable).

I hope this help you.